# Generate PDF from JavaScript or .NET Core

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, asp.net-core

What is the point of marking my question as a duplicate and pointing to questions that have no answers? Opening a windows and calling print is not an answer.

I am developing an App in Angular for the frontend and .NET Core for the Api.

I have been looking for a way to create a PDF file in either the browser or the server. I have looked at jsPDF for the client side and it doesn't render out my styles at all, I don't want to rasterize it.

I can't seem to find a solution to doing it server side with .NET Core. There are plenty of .NET Framework libraries and I have used a few before but I cannot find a HTML to PDF library for pure .NET Core. I don't want to have to install extra binaries on the server outside of the API project so anything Node based is not feasible.

I can't be the only one who would like to generate PDF files that look exactly like my HTML page in either .NET Core or client side JavaScript.